# Multiple ST2 Cursors

Tags: sublimetext2

I am in need of being able to select multiple cursors for thousands of lines that would then let me add content before each of them at the same time. Is there a way to select all and then select the multiple cursor option to put the cursor before each character of each line? Hope that does not sound confusing :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### On Windows / OS X

1. Make sure you have View > Word Wrap off
2. Select all: <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. Split into Lines:<kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
4. Put the cursor at the beginning of the line: <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though I don't know how well multiple selections works with thousands of lines.

1. Start with *Select All* or select the lines that you need to edit.
2. From the *Selection* menu -> *Split into lines*. This will create multiple selections, one for each line.
3. Move the cursor to the beginning of each line by using the <kbd>Home</kbd> key.
4. Insert your content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as was suggested in other answers, it will work perfectly fine, sublime can handle thousands of selections for sure, but it might get bit slow sometimes.

Use regex in search n' replace, that's what it's for.

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> opens search and replace tab
2. make sure "Regular expressions" is pressed, "wrap" is pressed and "in selections" is NOT pressed.
3. type ^ to top field, it will mean "beginning of line" in this context
4. type your text in bottom field
5. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> or whatever the shortcut is to "replace all"